# How to Submit a Query or a .sql file containing a query using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to run queries on spark. I have them all on my .sql files

Currently the way i am running is :

```
spark-sql --master yarn /home/myuser/query.sql
```

But as soon as the query completes the execution it comes inside the **spark-sql>** .... shell prompt And then the job status doesn't changes to Finished Successfully it shows RUNNING becoz the **spark-sql>** shell is active so i have to explicitly do **CTRL+C** to come out of the shell.

SO Basically i just want to submit a spark job which is actually a query using a shell script file and without getting inside any spark specific shell.

I don't want to write a query in a class file and then build a jar and then submit.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that -f option does the job for me.

```
spark-sql --master yarn -f /home/myuser/query.sql
```