# .sql file containing a query using spark-sql doesn't pick up the table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While running the below query, the table is getting picked up.

```
$ spark-sql --master yarn -f /foo/bar/hive-testbench/spark-queries-tpcds/q3.sql
```

The Application ID is getting generated, however, throwing the below error:

> Error in query: Table or view not found: date_dim; line 6 pos 5

Referred the URL:
[How to Submit a Query or a .sql file containing a query using spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839327/how-to-submit-a-query-or-a-sql-file-containing-a-query-using-spark-submit?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: sound like you have a specific issue, with your table, configuration or sql file.  If you want to be able to get an answer, you should [edit] your question and provide all the missing details (sql file, config details, output logs, etc)

Comment: did you try to specify db name? could be that current-db is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the db name. It generates an application id, however, don't see the App ID on Spark History Server.